# server.inject with hapijs not return the correct response

Tags: mongodb, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

I am trying to use Lab to test some code. However, for some reason when I put the right payload my code does nothing. The promise doesn't seem to get returned:

```
'use strict';

const Server = require('../server');

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/users',
    payload: JSON.stringify({ mobile: '3342329224' })
};

Server.inject(options, (response) => {

    if (response) {
        console.log(response.payload);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Nada');
    }
});
```

If I edit the code so that there is no payload or it doesn't match my Joi validation then it I get response:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"child \"mobile\" fails because [\"mobile\" must be larger than or equal to 10]","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":["mobile"]}}

module.exports = {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/users',
    config: {
        auth: false,
        handler: (request, reply) => {

            //looks up payload in db otherwise creates entry
            User.findOne({
                mobile: request.payload.mobile
            }, (err, user) => {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if (user) {
                    // uses twillio to send code
                    sendVerificationText(user, (err, result) => {

                        if (err){
                            throw err;
                        }
                        if (result === true) {
                            // this is what I expect to happen when testing
                            reply('code sent').code(201);
                        }
                        else {
                            throw Boom.badRequest(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // the user should exist so....
                    const user = new User();
                    user.mobile = request.payload.mobile;
                    user.admin = false;
                    user.save((err, user) => {

                        if (err) {
                            throw Boom.badRequest(err);
                        }
                        sendVerificationText(user, (err, result) => {

                            if (err){
                                throw err;
                            }
                            if (result === true) {
                                reply('code sent').code(201);
                            }
                            else {
                                throw Boom.badRequest(err);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        // Validate the payload against the Joi schema
        validate: {
            payload: createUserSchema
        }
    }
};
```

I should mention that this code works when I run the server and test the api by hand. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I suggest using something like chrome developer tools to inspect that actual request you are sending to the server, and compare it with request that you are using to test by hand.

Most likely something is slightly different in the request being generated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hapijs. But my first guess from reading the documentation, is perhaps your server code should be: request.mobile instead of request.payload.mobile? Just a guess I could be way off.

Comment: I am way off. I did a little research and tried to create a similar project. I found the issue that causes the joi validation to hang. Posting an answer with that find.

Comment: I suggest you don't throw errors, just return them to client with hapi's reply interface

Comment: createUserSchema:

`'use strict';

const Joi = require('joi');

const createUserSchema = Joi.object({
    mobile: Joi.number().min(10).required()
});

module.exports = createUserSchema;`

Comment: @Grouchy can we seen full code for tests?  As stated before you must not throw errors but handle them using reply interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the original answer not getting anywhere. I've gone back and tried with lab to recreate your test:
https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverlfow_Q_39432656/blob/master/test/users.js

It does not appear to hang for me. I get the expected response code sent. I put a couple of asserts into the function using the Code library ( new dependency ) per lab's documentation:

```
lab.test("user post", function (done) {

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/users',
        payload: JSON.stringify({ mobile: '3342329224' })
    };

    Server.inject(options, (response) => {

        if (response) {
            console.log(response.payload);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Nada');
        }

        Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(201);
        Code.expect(response.payload).to.equal("code sent");
        done();
    });
});
```

Curious what are you seeing as output when you run the test? Does the command line just hang for you? Check my github project for how the test is implemented for me for discrepancies. Hope this is of some help to you.

**Oh.. you know what you need to make sure you call done() inside your test for it to end ;)** Probably why it is hanging for you

**Original Answer for reference:**
I've recreated your environment to the best of my abilities. Got to say I like this hapi.js framework. Very nice! Quick way to get a server up. Thumbs up. Nice choice.

So here is what I found by mocking based on your posted code:
https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverlfow_Q_39432656

In that solution you will find where you set your validation:

```
validate: {
            payload: createUserSchema
        }
```

I assume **createUserSceme** is a function you are setting as the value of payload there. If it is a function it will cause the request to hang and never return! Hence the behaviour you are seeing as if the promise is never returned. Server never responds. If I change it to this...

```
validate: {
            payload: createUserSchema()
        }
```

Then we are all okay and the validation can continue. So the goal here is to make sure the value of validate is an object.

Mind you I have mocked your createUserSchema by a guess. So if you'd like to get to the bottom of the next problem. Please post more code, and I will gladly try and see if I can help more =)  ( off to watch some more of Nacros season 2, I'll check back tomorrow )

Comment: When I change that to a function I get `TypeError: createUserSchema is not a function`

Comment: Ok I was guessing that it was a function based on the variable name. Checking out new code you added.

Comment: @Grouchy  - I've updated my testing source to match your Joi schema https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverlfow_Q_39432656/commit/869f806ab5d69caf9eec783a451dfedbf026e672.   Everything works, and server does not hang.  My next guess would be to look at the function sendVerificationText.  It is possible that the problem is that sendVerificationText is not returning causing it to have the behaviour you are seeing. Are you able to post sendVerificationText as well?

Comment: Hi @Grouchy. I've taken time to implement the lab test as well. I noticed you didn't have any asserts I've added those. I used your code in your implementation. It is working for me ( does not seem like promise is not returned ). Maybe check my updated answer and github project for any differences?

Comment: @Grouchy found something possibly. Are you not calling done() inside your lab test function?

Comment: _Curious what are you seeing as output when you run the test? Does the command line just hang for you?_
`Timed out (2000ms) - Users user post`

I originally had it as a test, like you wrote, but the test kept failing so I wanted to see if I could just 'inject' in a script and get it to return a result.